# Positioning name of node label in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, labels

I have the following diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz, nth}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,bending,positioning, chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \draw[thick,]  (0,8) -- (0,0) node[left] {0};
        \draw[thick,]  (0,0) -- (8,0) node[right] {8};
        \draw[thick,]  (8,8) -- (8,0) node[left] {};
        \draw[thick,]  (8,8) -- (0,8) node[left] {8};

        \draw[thick,]  (4,0) -- (4,8) node[left] {};

        \fill (1, 4) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below]{$A$};
        \fill (2, 6) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below]{$B$};
        \fill (3, 2) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below]{$C$};
        \fill (4, 8) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below]{$D$};
        \fill (7, 3) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below]{$E$};
        \fill (6, 1) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below]{$F$};
        \fill (5, 7) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below]{$G$};
        \fill (3, 8) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below]{$H$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I position the caption of the node `$D$` both below and left, so that the line doesn't obscure the caption?

Comment: `\node[below left] {D},` ?

Comment: Oh.... below left works, but not left below? Didn't think that switching the order would help.

Comment: Logic is the same as naming horizon's sides: *south west* (=below left) and never *west south*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let convert comments to an answer: Logic for positioning nodes, labels is the same as it is at naming of horizon's sides. For example: always we say *south west* (synonym for below left) and newer *west south* (= left below) ...

Regarding your MWE: see if the following more concise code of your MWE is useful to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz, nth}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,bending,positioning, chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,
dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt,
              node contents={}},
                    ]
\draw[thick]  (0,8)      node[left] {8}
                -- (0,0) node[left] {0}
                -- (8,0) node[right] {8}
                -- (8,8) -- cycle;
\draw[thick,]  (4,0) -- (4,8) node[left] {};

\path (1,4) node[dot,label=below:$A$];
\path (2,6) node[dot,label=below:$B$];
\path (3,2) node[dot,label=below:$C$];
\path (4,8) node[dot,label=below left:$D$];
\path (7,3) node[dot,label=below:$E$];
\path (6,1) node[dot,label=below:$F$];
\path (5,7) node[dot,label=below:$G$];
\path (3,8) node[dot,label=below:$H$];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]