# drawing a network graph with node labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a graph in which nodes have labels. I want to put label for each node under it. I want to change the following code to draw a dot for node 5, and below the node, I want to have 5.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%auto, node distance=1.5cm, every loop/.style={},
                %thick,main node/.style={scale=0.7, 
                %circle,draw,font=\sffamily\small\bfseries}]
                dot/.style={fill,circle, minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0,node contents={}},
   circ/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=10pt,inner sep=0pt, node 
contents={}}]
\node[main node] (5) {5};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I wanted to ask how I can do that.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positioning name of node label in tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316638/positioning-name-of-node-label-in-tikzpicture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different ways of positioning labels  - please revert if required for any additions/ clarifications

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  auto, 
  node distance=1.5cm, 
  every loop/.style={},
  thick,
  main node/.style={scale=0.7, 
                    circle,
                    draw,
                    font=\sffamily\small\bfseries},
  dot/.style={fill,
                circle, 
                minimum size=5pt,
                inner sep=0,
                node contents={}},
  circ/.style={draw, 
                circle, 
                minimum size=10pt,
                inner sep=0pt, 
                node contents={}}
            ]
  \node[main node, label=above:$B$] at (0,0)(5) {5};
    \node[main node, label=below:$B$] at (0,-2)(5) {5};
      \node[main node, label=left:$B$] at (0,-4)(5) {5};
         \node[main node, label=right:$B$]at (0,-6) (5) {5};
    \node [circle,
            thin,
            inner sep=1pt,
            draw=red,
            fill=red!40,
            label={[label distance=1cm]30:$5$}] 
            at (0,-8){};     
  \end{tikzpicture}
```